# Wait for the content to fadeIn a div with jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a div, with a button.

1. when I press the button I `fadeOut()` the div
2. I load content from another page, with jQuery `ajax()`
3. when the content is loaded, I want to put this content into the div
4. only then, `fadeIn()` the div.

For now, I use this:

```
success: function (data) {
     $('#inside-choice').html(data);
     $('#inside-choice').fadeIn('slow');
},
```

But with this syntax, the fade in can start before that the content is totally loaded. How do I wait until the content is loaded before fading in the div?

Comment: "the fade in can start before that the content il totaly loaded", imo it can't. Data is only retrieved after the call succesfully retrieved the data.

Comment: Should work fine.. how big is your `data` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `promise()` :

```
success: function (data) {
     $('#inside-choice').html(data).promise().done(function(){
       $('#inside-choice').fadeIn('slow');
     });

},
```

https://api.jquery.com/promise/

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect ! :)